# Find the common members of two Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What is the easiest way to find the common members in two Javascript objects? **This question is not about equality.** I don't care about the values of each member, just that they exist in both objects.

Here's what I've done so far (using underscore.js):

```
_.intersection(_.keys({ firstName: 'John' }), _.keys({ firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' }))
```

This gives me a result of `['firstName']` as expected, but I would like to find an easier or more efficient way, preferably vanilla Javascript.

- Is there a better/easier way to do this with underscore?
- Is there a better/easier way to do this **without** underscore (preferred)?

Comment: you probably meant `_.intersecton`

Comment: In plain JS you could use ES5s [Object.keys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) on each object and pick the one with the least keys to check against the other, falling back to a for..in loop and *hasOwnProperty* test for older user agents.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, just iterate through the keys of one object and construct an array of the keys that the other object shares:

```
function commonKeys(obj1, obj2) {
  var keys = [];
  for(var i in obj1) {
    if(i in obj2) {
      keys.push(i);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}
```

Comment: +1 for wrapping it up in a nice function, and being 25 seconds faster :)

Comment: As for Phrogz, you need an own properties test 'cos *Object.keys* returns own properties. Also unlikely that the OP wants enumerable properties shared by inheritance. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean I should use `obj1.hasOwnProperty(i)` and `obj2.hasOwnProperty(i)` tests instead because `i` might be a user-defined enumerable prototype member?

Comment: @PeterOlson Yes, that's what he means. However, I maintain that such a test is [no longer appropriate](http://phrogz.net/death-to-hasownproperty) in an era of [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FdefineProperty). In short: if someone put an enumerable property on `Object.prototype`, you should probably believe them, since they had the choice to not do so.

Comment: @Phrogz—you should come from a defensive perspective where you have no idea where objects come from or what properties they have inherited. Also, the OP uses _.keys, which is a pseudonym or replacement for Objec.keys (depending on whether the host is ES5 or earlier), which only returns own properties.

Comment: How would this look if you wanted to extend to 3 or more objects?

Answer (score 5):

This will work for modern browsers:

```
function commonKeys(a, b) {
    return Object.keys(a).filter(function (key) { 
        return b.hasOwnProperty(key); 
    });
};

// ["firstName"]
commonKeys({ firstName: 'John' }, { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' });
```

Comment: +1 love the simplicity of this solution, I'll have to test it to see if it works in my scenario. I have to support back to IE6 <cringe />. Hoping it works with the compatibility solution shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: If you have to support back to IE6, you'll have to define an `Array.prototype.filter`, too. The simplicity might not be worth the extra code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var common = [];
for (var key in obj2) if (key in obj1) common.push(key);
```

**Edit for RobG**: If you happen to be working in an environment that includes code that is not your own, **and** you do not trust the author(s) to have extended `Object.prototype` [correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FdefineProperty), then you *might* want to do:

```
var common = [];
for (var k in obj2) if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(k) && obj1.hasOwnProperty(k)) common.push(k);
```

However, as I have stated in the comments below, I have written an article (with an inflammatory title) about why I believe that this used to be good advice, but is good advice no longer:
http://phrogz.net/death-to-hasownproperty

Comment: You need to add an own properties test: `if (obj2.hasOwnProprerty(key) && ...)...`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered but I wanted to offer an "underscore" way of doing it. I am also hoping that people will discuss the best "underscore" way of doing it here too.

```
var user1 = { firstName: 'John' }, user2 = { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' };

_.keys(_.pick(user1, _.keys(user2)))
```

that is my best shot at it, it doesn't reduct the underscore primitives from the original question so maybe this is the best you can do.

Here is the original question in my format for reference

```
_.intersection(_.keys(user1), _.keys(user2))
```

Comment: actually an interesting outcome of this is that the original way of doing it supports having null for either value user1 or user2. From what i can see actually the original question is the "right" way to do this in underscore.